# Output GitLog with Java Processbuilder to File

Tags: java, processbuilder, git-log

I create a Programm in Java which should automatic create a log file with gitlog and analyze this file.
But i have a Problem with Gitlog.
I created a Method who start `git log` in cmd and print this in a file out.

The programm start gitlog an show this in cmd, but the new file is empty.

How can i output this log in a file ?

My Method :

```
Path LogPath = Paths.get("C:/Users/User/Code/code1");

List<String> cmds = Arrays.asList("cmd.exe", "/C", "start", "git", "log");
ProcessBuilder builder = new ProcessBuilder(cmds);
builder.directory(new File("C:/Users/User/Code/code1/git"));

builder.redirectOutput(ProcessBuilder.Redirect.to( LogPath.resolve("gitlog.txt").toFile() ) );

Process process = builder.start();
```

Comment: Change the process arguments as `Arrays.asList("git", "log")`. This should do the job.

Comment: thx, this works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Solution**

This works for me :

```
List<String> cmds = Arrays.asList("git", "log");
```